# Regular expression with Unicode Characters

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a regular expression, I need to catch the characters , ⚡,❓ and others in a string. If this character is at the beginning of the line and without a space, insert a space on the right, if the character is at the end of the line and without a space in front of it, insert a space on the left. And if the character is in the middle of the line without spaces, insert spaces on the left and right. So far, all I can do is get the character itself '`/[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}]/u`'

Comment: Maybe `trim(preg_replace('/\s*([\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}]+)\s*/u', ' $1 ', $text))`?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, how in this case can I keep spaces at the edges of the line?

Comment: That is not what you want according to question (but you can simply remove the `trim`).

Comment: I mean if a line starts and ends with a few spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it's lengthy but I interpreted your question as such:

- Keep leading/trailing spaces intact;
- Keep consecutive emoticons intact.

Therefor, try:

```
(?:(?<![\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}\s]|^)(?=[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}])|(?<=[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}])(?!$|[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}\s]))
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/V1bem0/1)

It's lengthy, but it's basically an non-capture group which holds two alternatives;

- Match a position that is not preceded by emoticon, start-line or space but is followed by emoticon;
- Match a position that is not followed by emoticon, end-line or space but is preceded by emoticon.

Comment: Note that `(?!$|\s|[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}])` = `(?!$|[\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}\s])`  = `(?=[^\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}\s])`. And `(?<![\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}]|^|\s)` = `(?<=[^\s\x{000ff}-\x{fffff}])`